# Input type date - date range same for every year

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a contact form with 2 inputs of type *date*. I've set `min` and `max` date but they are set for the current year only. Is there a way to put the selected date range for every year?

https://jsfiddle.net/3akf49jr/

HTML

```
<form>
  <label for="">Arrival date</label>
  <input type="date" name="" min="2019-09-01" max="2019-10-01" id="minDate">
  <label for="">Departure date</label>
  <input type="date" name="" max="2019-10-01" id="maxDate">
</form>
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('minDate').onchange = function () {
  document.getElementById('maxDate').setAttribute('min',  this.value);
};
```

I also have a script that restricts dates in the second field based on a selected date in the first date field. I would like that functionality to remain.

Comment: just set `max` to something like 2030 or 3030 :)

Comment: That is not what I want. I have range from 01-01 to 01-20. Only dates in that range can be picked. And I want that range for every year.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that with built-in input type date. I suggest you to use jquery ui datepicker or any other datepicker